# How to Modify Class Print Output

Tags: ruby

I have some classes that have large instance variables attached to them. When I initialize these classes the large instance variables attached to them are outputted along with them resulting in the output taking the entirety of my shell and being kinda annoying. Is there a way I can override what the output of my class should be when its returned in a terminal to avoid this?

Comment: IMO the only good answer here is to refactor your code so it's easier to inspect and debug small parts at a time.

Comment: They didn't tag rails.

Comment: They didn't tag "other libs".

Comment: You're playing by yourself, Sergio.

Answer (score 2):

I know what you mean. Every once in a while I have to work with an object that has a print-out of several screens. And when it's not a single object, it's a collection.

I do this to prevent it from flooding my screen

```
my_obj = get_a_huge_object_or_collection; nil
```

In this case, `nil` becomes the value of this expression and is printed out.

But if you really want to permanently alter how your objects print to the console, you can override `inspect`.

Answer (score 2):

Sergio Tulentsev already provided an answer on how to suppress verbose output.

Another option might be to change how an instance of that class is outputted. This can be done by defining a custom `inspect` method.

Imagine you have a class `Foo`like this:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :bar
end
```

then you would see output like this:

```
foo = Foo.new
foo.bar = "extremely long value"

foo
#=> #<Foo:0x00007ffab9aaf3f0 @bar="extremely long value">
```

But when you add a custom `inspect` method to your class then you can control how the output looks like, and you can, for example, truncate long attributes or can only show the most interesting values:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :bar

  def inspect
    "#<Foo @bar=\"#{bar[0,8]}...\">"
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.bar = "extremely long value"

foo
#=> #<Foo @bar="extremel..."
```

Comment: my answer has a bit on `inspect` too :)

Comment: Nice, also works for `"a very short value that isn't long at all"` :)